# Micro front end asset loading issue on base app

Tags: angular, reactjs, micro-frontend

I've created two micro apps using Angular & React Js and base/container app in Angular.
Micro apps are running on different ports and base app importing the main.js file from specific ports.
I've achieved this functionality by following this article- https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/create-micro-frontends-using-web-components-with-support-for-angular-and-react-2d6db18f557a.
Here he has copied assets of each micro apps into base app but is there any better approach by which i can independently load the asset into base app on run time and access base app server can access.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by passing the host to the render function. So basically I use the variable host near each image and it will have full URL. If you load the microfrontend separate host will be empty so it should load from same host.

```
window.renderHeader = (containerId, history, host) => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <App history={history} host={host} />,        
        document.getElementById(containerId),
    );
};
```

In the container I then do

```
const renderMicroFrontend = () => {
    window[`render${name}`](`${name}-container`, history, host);
};
```

And in the HTML

```
function App({history, host}) {
    return (
        <div className="header">
            <div className="logo">
                <img src={host + "/logo.png"} alt="logo" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```